# Parameters choice for ALL

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

I have to include a value of 0 for "ALL" in my parameter. There is not a value of 0 located anywhere in that table, and it always returns 0 results. All of the other values are returning the correct results. How can I configure this?

[image]

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: How do I accept? Would be more than willing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to get all rows, regardless of `PAT_ENC.CANCEL_REASON_C` if your parameter `CancelReason` is 0.

Every row that filters to `true` will be returned. If you want to ignore a term  (`0 -> all` is equivalent to ignore reason) come up with a term that logically "eliminates" your term. This can be done by concatenating with `or` and an expression that evaluates to `true`.

To achieve this alter your filter condition to the following:

```
({PAT_ENC.CANCEL_REASON_C} = {?CancelReason} or {?CancelReason} = 0)
and 
// the rest of your filter
```

Watch out for the parentheses - They are necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked out perfectly. I really appreciate all of the help.